# How to import the same component multiple times in order to set different displayNames?

Tags: reactjs, components, displayname-attribute

I'm importing the `Button` component from our design-system. I want to import it multiple times by renaming it (e.g. `import {Button as Btn, Button as MyBtn} from 'design-system'` and then assign different `displayName` to them, via:

```
Btn.displayName = 'Btn';
MyBtn.displayName = 'MyBtn';
```

React however is giving `MyBtn` to all the Buttons present in the component. How can I achieve my objective?